# Let $f(1)= 4, f'(x)= \sum_{k=0}^∞ \frac{(-1)^{k} (x-1)^{k}}{(k+1)!}$ then find $f''(1)$.

Tags: calculus

Let $f(1)= 4, f'(x)= \sum_{k=0}^∞ \frac{(-1)^{k} (x-1)^{k}}{(k+1)!}$ then find $f''(1)$.

I directly differentiated $f'(x)$ and put $x=1$, then I got $0$.
If I expand the series $f'(x)$ then then coefficient of $(x-1)$ is $f"(1)$, which is $-1/2$.

Answer is given $-1/2$.

What is the problem in direct differentiation$?$
And how do we find derivative at a point in such cases$?$

Comment: There is something named https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence, taking derivative of a sum is not always equals to sum of derivative, and the same for integrals.

Comment: Are you familiar with uniform convergence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your sum is

$$f'(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k} (x-1)^{k}}{(k+1)!} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Differentiating this term by term gives

$$f''(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k(-1)^{k} (x-1)^{k-1}}{(k+1)!} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

The first term, i.e., for $k = 0$, is $0$. The second term, i.e., for $k = 1$, is $\frac{(-1)^{1}(x-1)^{1-1}}{(1+1)!} = \frac{-1(1)}{2!} = -\frac{1}{2}$ since $(x - 1)^{0} = 1$. All other terms have a factor of $x - 1$ to a power of $1$ or higher so, at $x = 1$, they would all be $0$, thus resulting in

$$f''(1) = -\frac{1}{2} \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

which matches the given answer. If I understood your question correctly, this confirms what you also got.

Note the original derivative series is basically a modified version of the [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) for the exponential function (and, thus, as explained in the [Exponential function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#Exponential_function) section of Wikipedia's "Uniform convergence" article, the result is uniformly convergent, with this being a requirement for term by term differentiation, as done in \eqref{eq2A}). To see this, you have

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
f'(x) & = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k} (x-1)^{k}}{(k+1)!} \\
& = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(1-x)^{k}}{(k+1)!} \\
& = \frac{1}{1-x}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(1-x)^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}\right) \\
& = \frac{1}{1-x}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(1-x)^{k}}{k!}\right) \\
& = \frac{1}{1-x}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(1-x)^{k}}{k!} - 1\right) \\
& = \frac{1}{1-x}\left(e^{1-x} - 1\right) \\
& = \frac{e^{1-x} - 1}{1-x}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

I assume you used this closed form expression when you stated you directly differentiated $f'(x)$ and then substituted $x = 1$. Well, differentiating \eqref{eq4A} gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
f''(x) & = \frac{-e^{1-x}}{1-x} + \frac{(-1)(e^{1-x} - 1)}{(-1)(1-x)^2} \\
& = \frac{(-e^{1-x})(1-x) + (e^{1-x} - 1)}{(1-x)^2} \\
& = \frac{x\left(e^{1-x}\right) - 1}{(1-x)^2}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

Since $f''(x)$ is indeterminate at $x = 1$, I'll use [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) twice to get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
f''(1) & = \lim_{x \to 1}\frac{x\left(e^{1-x}\right) - 1}{(1-x)^2} \\
& = \lim_{x \to 1}\frac{\left(1 - x\right)\left(e^{1-x}\right)}{2(1-x)(-1)} \\
& = \lim_{x \to 1}\frac{\left(x - 2\right)\left(e^{1-x}\right)}{2} \\
& = -\frac{1}{2}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

As you can see, the same value is obtained this way as well.